# Angular - update badge number in template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

This is my controller:

```
.controller('FilterCtrl', function($scope, $http, tagsService, speciesService) {
    $scope.tags = tagsService.getTags();
    $scope.fileNameChanged = function(event) {
        q = []
        _.each($(event).find(":selected"), function(el) {
            if ( $(el).text().trim() !== "" ) {
                q.push($(el).text().trim()) 
            }
        })
        q = q.join('&')
        s = speciesService.getList(q)
    }
})
```

This is a tab with a badge associated to it:

```
  <ion-tab title="List" icon="icon ion-navicon-round" href="#/tab/list" badge="0" badge-style="badge-assertive">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-list"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

Here is the speciesService:

```
.factory('speciesService', function($http) {
  var speciesService = {};
  speciesService.data = {};
  speciesService.getList = function (q) {
   $http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/species/?format=json&tags=" + q, {})
       .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            speciesService.data.species = data;
            console.log(speciesService.data.species.objects.length);
        })
      // .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //     console.log(status)
      //     tags = [];
      //   });
      return speciesService.data;
  }

  return speciesService;
```

When the user chooses options in a select input, I am requesting data from the server with **speciesService**. Then after that I want to update the badge based on the count I have for the returned objects.

Im not sure how you connect this speciesService to the badge witch is in another template.

Comment: need to bind `badge=""` to scope variable that is bound to `speciesService.data` or gets updated by an event broadcast

Answer (score 2):

Pretending I didn't notice the fact that you are using jQuery and accessing the DOM from inside your controller:

```
.controller('FilterCtrl', function($scope, $http, tagsService, speciesService) {
    $scope.speciesData = speciesService.data;
    ...

<ion-tab ... badge="{{speciesData.species.length}}"
```